# How to float 3 divs with margin left & right 0px?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to float 3 divs next to each other. the 1st one on the left side should lean to the left, the 2nd should be exactly in the middle and the 3rd one should lean to the right.

I tried it with float but can't center the middle one. How can I fix this?

HTML

```
<div class="select_3_left">
</div>
    <div class="vertical_line"></div>
<div class="select_3_middle">
</div>
    <div class="vertical_line"></div>
<div class="select_3_right">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.select_3_left{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: red;
    }

.select_3_middle{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background: green;
    }

.select_3_right{
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background: blues;
    }

.vertical_line{
    float: left;
    height: 330px;
    width: 1px;
    background: silver;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs have no height, so they do not do much currently.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jF5Dv/)

```
    .select_3_left{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
    }

.select_3_middle{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height:100px;
    background: green;
    }

.select_3_right{
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height:100px;
    background: blue;
    }

.vertical_line{
    float: left;
    height: 330px;
    width: 1px;
    background: silver;
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution that involves less code:

HTML:

```
<div class="select first"></div>
<div class="select"></div>
<div class="select"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.select {
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;    
    height: 330px;
    border-left: 1px solid silver;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;    
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
.select.first {
    border: none;    
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qBW5g/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I used it :) +1

Answer (score 0):

change the middle to `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: I tried that before, but this works only if I remove the "float:left" for the middle div from the CSS. But then the right divs moves to the bottom...